# Security Exception when using LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

I've built an MVC 2 application (ASP.net 3.5) using Entity Framework, and am doing my querying with LINQ. I'm trying to deploy to a shared host (1&1). The only (possibly) relevant restriction I'm aware of is that they don't allow unmanaged code, though I'm not using any to my knowledge.

Here are the last couple lines of my stack trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Data.Objects.LightweightCodeGenerator.ValidateSetterProperty(RuntimeMethodHandle setterMethodHandle, MethodInfo& setterMethodInfo, Type& realType) +28
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.CreatePropertyBindings(StructuredColumnMap columnMap, Type clrType, ReadOnlyMetadataCollection`1 properties) +142
....
```

I do not have the option of setting my application to Full trust.

My question now is this: is using Linq-to-entities still possible in my environment? If not, what alternatives are there that would require the least rework? Entity Framework is handling things like validation for me, so I'd like not to have to scrap it.

Comment: What does your unmanaged code look like?

Comment: I don't have unmanaged code that I'm aware of, but that's the only restriction my host explicitly states which I think could possibly be relevant. I'm updating my post with the last few lines of my stack trace. I feel like it could be helpful.

Comment: The solution I ended up going with was using Linq-to-SQL. It doesn't require the same server permissions as Linq-to-Entities, and I was able to keep most of my code the same (most importantly, my validation through data annotations). Updating foreign keys is also simpler in Linq-to-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx and search for full-trust word, you will see all basic rights EF needs to run when in partial trust mode.

Comment: I did come across that, and linked to it in an email to my hosting provider. I'm not sure if they allow those things though. I do have copies of their .config files, but I don't know how to interpret them against that MS link.